# iOS position UILabel in circle view

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I defined a view which contains an UImageView and a UILabel. I setted constraints for each elements.

In wanted to do a circle with the first view, so I did that in the code :

```
    self.mainView.layer.cornerRadius = self.mainView.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.mainView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

So it works, I have a circle, BUT the UImageView and the UILabel seems don't follow the constraints setted in the storyboard.

For example, on my UILabel, I setted a margin left and right 5px to the mainView, but I can see my UILabel "out" the mainView....

I tried to do a "setNeedsUpdateConstraints", but it's not the solution.

So, what I need to do to have my UILabel correctly positioned ?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your label a mainView subview?

Comment: Yes, it's a subview of my UIView "mainView".

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Are all the others constraints working properly? Did you try deleting the app on the device?

Comment: Yes it works properly, because if I delete the code to have a circle, the UILabel is fine positionned.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
 self.mainView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when changing the `mainView`'s layer you are not actually changing the bounds of the view. The bounds of the view are still represented in a rectangle manner. what you need to do is change the width constraint of the `UILable`.

To do so just create a autolayout constrain to your UILable (is you don't have it already). Control-Drag it to your viewController and change it dynamically using the `constant` value in the constraint.

If you don't need to set it dynamically just set the left & right margins to a bigger margin

Comment: I didn't set a width constraint, because I just want my UILabel centered with a margin left & right => 5px.

Comment: So I don't understand it's impossible to say to my UILabel to reposition after the update of my mainView ? (or to say to my mainView to reposition its subviews.)

Comment: the problem is not in re positioning. because the autolayout is working good. the frame of the view did not changed after setting new value to the cornerRadius. So in fact the label is still centered.

Comment: Oh okay, I understood.. But I don't see how to do to center properly the label on the circle view :/

Comment: you want the label to be centered vertically & horizontally?

Comment: Nop, my label is on the "bottom" of the view. So I just want to have it centered horizontally.

Comment: and you want it to fit inside the circle?

Comment: just set the left & right margins to a bigger margin. You can try to calculate it, but i believe it's kinda of an over kill

Comment: argh, ok... I don't like that :D

Comment: yeah, i know..it's not one of my favorite ways to do this. You can try to set the label to be at the bottom of the view (right below it). This will also prevent situations where there's a image with the same color as the label thus the text is not visible